# Data is not being POSTed in python. No errors given by compiler

Tags: python, api, post

I'm trying to POST data to an api, after execution the compiler does not give any errors, but the data is not showing in the database.

```
import requests
endpoint = "http://192.168.10.2:8085/api/customer"
myObj = {"customer_id": 900, 
    "customer_code": "qwertyuiop", 
    "ustomer_name": "lion", 
    "contact": "030190000", 
    "address": "lane"}
x = requests.post(url = endpoint, data = myObj)
```

Edit:
when I try to do

```
print(x.text)
```

I get this error:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"00-9b47b6c7ce1f14499652ba95b3faca3a-cc8e04f53a002647-00"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some more information? How are you trying to run this code? You mention the compile, but not the exact call you're making to run this. If it's a simple script, this might help: https://realpython.com/python-main-function/#a-basic-python-main

Comment: @ThePjot I'm creating a qml application from where data will be POSTed to the api. Before doing that I decided to do a simple test run with basic python to see if the data was being POSTed. The data was not being POSTed, so I then went to " https://reqbin.com/ " and tried to POST data from there and it worked. I can't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I needed to use json (which takes a dictionary) instead of data (which takes a string).

```
import json
import requests

payload = {"customer_id": 456, "customer_code": "fakhr", "customer_name": "fakhr", "contact": "fakhr", "address": "fakhr"}
r = requests.post("http://192.168.10.2:8085/api/customer", json=payload)
print(r.text)
```